# Not able to close DataInputStream of server socket in Android

Tags: android, sockets

On destroying my Application I want to close the Socket connection to the Server and close the DataInputStream. So i have put up the following code in my MainActivity.

```
public void onDestroy()
    {
        Log.d("TAG", "DESTROYING");
        Read_table.flag=false;
        try
        {
            Read_table.soc.close();
            Read_table.input.close();

        } catch (IOException e)
        {   Log.d("TAG", "Exception");

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onDestroy();  
    }
```

ReadTable is a service having a thread which is reading Data From Server. When i Remove this application from the Tray, the onDestroy() method of main Activity Executes.

But on the Server side I am still able to write to the DataInputStream, and there is No IOException so i could delete it from Servers Memory.

Comment: the first thing that should be executed is the super method not the last one

Answer (score 1):

> But on the Server side I am still able to write to the DataInputStream and there is no `IOException`

For a few writes, yes, but you will eventually get `IOException: connection reset by peer`, when you should close the socket. This is basically because of the socket send buffer at the sender.

If the server had *read* from the socket, it would have got end of stream.

Comment: Thanks this is what is happening.